# Binding Shift-Enter to insert a newline without evaluating the current expression

Tags: bash, vi, xterm, xmodmap

I try to bind `Shift-Enter` to insert a newline without evaluating the current expression in the terminal and in repl modes. Reading through the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap), I tried setting this in my `~/.Xmodmap` file and reloading `~/.Xmodmap` with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`. This however, does not work. Here is my detailed setup:

content of:

```
    ~/.Xmodmap:
    keysym Return = Return Linefeed
```

`~/.Xmodmap` is automatically resourced when logging in by setting:

```
    if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
        xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap

    fi
```

in my `~/.xinitrc`.

*Additional relevant info:*

(1) I set vi editing mode on in my `~/.bashrc` and my `~/.inputrc`. However, results did not differ when taking these options out.

(2) Using `keysym Return = Return Linefeed` was suggested [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia).* Other methods did not work either.

(3) My `$TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`.

Thanks for any help!

---

*Update: The solution suggested on this page (if still to be found) cannot work in the specific case discussed there as the programming language is using its own repl implementation. So this does not have any bearing on the case at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy answer is to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

---

Binding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to `Linefeed` makes it send `^J` = control-J = `\n` = `\012` (instead of `^M` = `\r` = `\015`). That's only part of what you need to do: by default, both keys are bound to executing the current line in bash. You need to change the binding for ^J in your `.inputrc` to insert a literal (`^V` = `\026`) newline:

```
"\n": self-insert
```

Alternatively, bind the key in your `.bashrc`:

```
bind -m vi-command '"\n": self-insert'
bind -m vi-insert '"\n": self-insert'
```

---

Changing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to `Linefeed` may have undesirable side effects — it's often useful to have <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> equivalent to <kbd>Return</kbd> so that you can type <kbd>Return</kbd> quickly even when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is down. I would recommend instead changing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to insert a linefeed in XTerm. You can do that in your `~/.Xresources` (or wherever you put your X resources):

```
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override Ctrl<Key>Return: string("\012")
```

Comment: Thank you @Gilles! Just to give some feedback: Binding `Shift-Return` with the `~/.inputrc` option did not work for me. But the `~/.bashrc` solution did. The last suggestion is really good but it did not work when I tried.